# Infinite countable subset such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=0$, whenever $a,b \notin S$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose there is an infinite countable subset $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=0$, when ever $a,b \notin S$. Show that $f=0$.

I have seen a proof of this with $f$ positive by cutting $[a,b] $ into infintely many subintervals . But here $f$ is not positive. Also, the part where it says "there is an infinite countable subset $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx=0$, whenever $a,b \notin S$ throws me off a bit. Why do we need such condition?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $S$ is countable the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (each nonempty open interval is uncountable, hence hits $\mathbb{R}\setminus S$). Fix any $a \notin S$. Then $F(x):= \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with $F(x)=0$ $(x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus S)$. Hence $F(x)=0$ $(x \in \mathbb{R})$, thus $f(x)=F'(x)=0$ $(x \in \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: How did we conclude$f(x)=F'(x)=0$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @korn This follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus. If $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ ist continuous  then $F(x):= \int_a^x f(t) dt$  ($a$ fixed) is a primitive of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction, suppose that $f\neq 0$. It exists $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(c) \neq 0$. Without loss of generality, we can suppose $f(c) \gt 0$. As $f$ is supposed to be continuous, we can find an interval $I$ of positive length such that $c \in I$ and $f$ is positive on $I$. As $S$ is countable, we can find $a,b \in I \setminus S$. Finally, we get the contradiction $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx\gt 0$.